# How to use new line (\n) with italic in ggplot title in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, newline, typography

I want a plot title that uses italics and two lines. I can't figure out how to make such a title.

```
# Sample data
> dput(samp1)
structure(list(phase = c("Years 2012-2016", "Years 2012-2016", 
"Years 2012-2016", "Years 2012-2016", "Years 2012-2016"), name = c("Camden", 
"Camden", "Camden", "Camden", "Camden"), value = c(37.0665188470067, 
49.4146341463415, 63.1718403547672, 44.6607538802661, 33.2638580931264
), county = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Camden County", 
"Guilford County", "Pasquotank County", "Wake County"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I tried

```
library(tidyverse)

mytesttitle <- expression(atop(paste("Summary of Days with ",italic(Weather),"\nSuited with extra words to make this longer, 2012-2021")))

ggplot(data=samp1) + geom_boxplot(aes(y=value))+
  labs( y="Number of Days",
  title=mytesttitle) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

and there is no new line. The title bleeds off the viewing area. Also the title has a lot of space between the text and the border of the plot itself:

[image: an image of plot with title offscreen]

I also tried:

```
mytesttitle <- expression(paste("Summary of Days with ",italic("Weather"),"\nMore Words Make This Longer Suited, 2012-2021"))

ggplot(data=samp1) + geom_boxplot(aes(y=value))+
 labs( y="Number of Days",
 title=mytesttitle) + #"Summary of Days with Weather\nSuited, 2012-2021") +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
 plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

and that was similar to above, just center-justified and less space between text and border of plot.

If I drop the italics and just use `\n`, like this:

```
mytesttitle <- expression(paste("Summary of Days with\nWeather Suited, 2012-2021"))
ggplot(data=samp1) + geom_boxplot(aes(y=value))+
 labs( y="Number of Days",
 title=mytesttitle) +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

I obviously lack the italics. The title goes outside the viewable area as the following:

[image]

How do I get italics and a new line to work in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of using `atop` actually works if you split the two parts of your phrase with a comma:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mytesttitle <- expression(atop(
  paste("Summary of Days with ", italic(Weather)),
  "Suited with extra words to make this longer, 2012-2021"
))

ggplot(data=samp1) + geom_boxplot(aes(y=value))+
  labs( y="Number of Days",
        title=mytesttitle) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

Another possible route would be to use `plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown()` to do italics and new line:

```r
ggplot(data=samp1) + geom_boxplot(aes(y=value))+
  labs( y="Number of Days",
        title="Summary of Days with *Weather*\n\nSuited with extra words to make this longer, 2012-2021") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So `atop` actually needs to be closed around just the fragment that will be on first line. And one needs *two* `\n` in the `title` when using the `ggtext::element_markdown()`.

Comment: In the first example you're passing 2 arguments separately to `atop`, to put `paste("Summary of Days with ", italic(Weather))` on top of `"Suited with extra words to make this longer, 2012-2021"` - your code had the two parts wrapped in `paste`. Yes the markdown version works with `\n\n` or actually `<br>` too if you want less space.

Answer (score 1):

One posible solution is use `subtitle` to set your second part of title:

```
mytesttitle <- expression(paste("Summary of Days with", italic("Weather")))
ggplot(data=samp1) + geom_boxplot(aes(y=value)) +
  #mdthemes::md_theme_classic() +
  ggtitle(mytesttitle, subtitle = "Suited with extra words to make this longer, 2012-2021") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        #title = element_text(size = 5),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, line = 0.6, size = 12)
        , plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, line = 0.6, size =12)
        )
```

[image]